# Save PDF automatically?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am creating a pdf with the jsPDF, I already have it but I want to wait for my document in automatic in a specific route that I have fixed

I know this `doc.save();` but this function asks you where you want to store it, there will be another function that does not ask and goes directly to the route that I have fixed.

Comment: Please post in English.

Comment: hello I am creating a pdf with the jsPDF, I already have it but I want to wait for my document in automatic in a specific route that I have fixed

I know this doc.save (); but this function asks you where you want to store it, there will be another function that does not ask and goes directly to the route that I have fixed.

Comment: Javascript can't write directly to files, it has to ask the user to select a file to save in. This is a security feature to prevent web sites from overwriting files without permission.

Comment: @Barmar I can't help but wonder if something was lost in translation. Maybe OP intends to upload the "saved" file?